# what if an application doesn't handle system event?

Tags: android

I'm newbie of developing android applications.

When I study system events from `BroadcastReceiver` and system `Service`, I get to wonder what happens if an application doesn't handle this event.

I heard registering the listener or overriding a method is necessary for handling the system event.

But if I didn't register, does the application not operate properly or my application crashes?

Thank you for your answer in advance. have a nice day.

Comment: What type of system events are you talking about?

Comment: Hi, I do not understand. What issue are you facing actually

Comment: I meant, system events like incoming phone calls or alarm service

Comment: And I wondered what happens in my app if the code handling this type of events doesnt exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I heard registering the listener or overriding a method is necessary
>   for handling the system event.
>
> But if I didn't register, does the application not operate properly or
>   my application crashes?

If you didn't register for any `Service` or `BroadcastReceiver` your application won't crash.

If you register for `Service` or `BroadcastReceiver` and provide blank implementation even in that case your application won't crash  **but that is not recommended** as it is useless code to leave blank implementation for `Service`.

Answer (score 2):

Your application will not crash. Those system events are not mandatory to use only when you have some operation to be done when those events occur. For example you want to disable wifi related work when battery is low. So here system event will help you to know when battery is low, so you can do desired task.